# How best to store a list of objects belonging to a user in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm writing an ASP.NET MVC web application that tracks characters from a game. We're using a code-first approach to make the database. One of the use cases is that the items belonging to each character be stored so they can be displayed in an inventory view.

I'm fairly new to ASP.NET MVC and I'm wondering what the best way is to store item objects that belong to the user? At the moment I have a lists of each type of item (see below). Will this approach work with Entity Framework?

```
public class Character : ParentClass
{
    public List<Skill> Skills { get; set; }
    public List<Armour> Armours { get; set; }
    public List<Weapon> Weapons { get; set; }
    public List<MagicItem> MagicItems { get; set; }
    public List<AdventuringGear> AdventuringGears { get; set; }
}
```

Will Entity Framework automatically keep track of the foreign keys that link, say, a sword to the character?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Mason, and welcome to Stack Overflow!
Since the answer to your question actually depends on which version of .NET and EntityFramework you're running on, could you please specify them?
E.g.: "running on .NET Framework 4.8 and EF 5" or "running on .NET Core 3.1 and EF Core 6.4" or "running on .NET 5 and EF Core 6", etc...
Thanks! :)

Comment: `Will Entity Framework automatically keep track of the foreign keys that link`, yes, it is designed for this.

Comment: *Will this approach work with Entity Framework?* Short answer: yes. But your question is too premature to answer, really. Or opinion-based (meaning: off-topic) if you want to discuss the suitability of your design.

Comment: @ClaudioValerio EF 6.2.0 and .NET Framework 4.7.2. Thanks for pulling up these errors, I should have disclosed versions in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> At the moment I have a lists of each type of item (see below). Will this approach work with Entity Framework?

Yes.  Although the preferred idiom for EF is

```
public virtual ICollection<Skill> Skills { get; } = new HashSet<Skill>();
```

`virtual` to enable Lazy Loading, and a `HashSet` as there's no inherent ordering in the database, and initialized to an empty collection for convenience.

> Will Entity Framework automatically keep track of the foreign keys that link, say, a sword to the character?

Yes.  If you don't model `Skill` with a `CharacterId` foreign key property, EF will create one in the database behind the scenes.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I haven't modelled the skill class with a CharacterId. Since posting I have seen answers that also say to use a Collection instead, I think I will change the classes to use this type instead.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! this approach will work however, it depends on quiet a few things. I am assuming other pre-requisites are met.
For Example your correct EF version and .NET version.

Comment: I appreciate the fast reply, I have included the versions of both in a reply to a comment on the original question.

Comment: Oh no worries, just trying to help out.